# AngularJS View Not Updating Using Defer and Factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am currently having an issue where when I try to create a new setting my view is not being updated until I refresh the page. Can anyone point me into the right direction? If I am going about this the wrong way please let me know a better way to do this.

```
app.factory('SettingsFactory', function ($http, $q) {
//$scope.settingData = {}

return {
  getAllOptionsAsync: function(callback) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/settings').success(callback);
  },
  deleteOptionAsync: function(id) {
    //console.log('reached');
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.delete('/api/settings/' + id);
  },
  createOptionAsync: function(settingData) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/api/settings', settingData).success(function(data) { console.log(data); 
                                                deferred.resolve(data);
                                               // console.log(deferred.promise);
                                                return deferred.promise;
                                              });
  }


};


});


var controllers = {};
controllers.SettingsController = function($scope, SettingsFactory) {

//$scope.settings = SettingService.list();
SettingsFactory.getAllOptionsAsync(function(results) {
  //console.log(results);
  $scope.settings = results;
});

$scope.create = function() {
               // console.log('called');
               // console.log($scope.formData);
                SettingsFactory.createOptionAsync($scope.formData).then(function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  $scope.settings = data;
                });
              } 

 $scope.delete = function(id) {
                //console.log(id.entity._id);
                SettingsFactory.deleteOptionAsync(id.entity._id);
              }


$scope.gridOptions = { 
data: 'settings',
multiSelect: false,
columnDefs: [
  {field: 'option'},
  {field: 'value'},
  {displayName: 'Edit', cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="open(settings._id)" >Edit</button> <button id="deleteBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="delete(row)" >Edit</button> '}
]
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the then or anytime you are updating the scope in a callback you need to wrap the $scope.settings=data with a scope.apply.

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.settings=data;
 });
```

Typed out on phone so there might be an error.

Comment: I have updated my code to include:  `$scope.create = function() {
                   
                          SettingsFactory.createOptionAsync($scope.formData).then(function(data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      $scope.$apply(function(data) {
                        $scope.settings= data;
                      });
                      console.log(data);
                      
                    });
                  }`

I am now getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: The scope.apply function doesn't have a parameter like my example.  Should be function () instead of function (data)